# How to sum a particular column using it's column names

Tags: vba

I have tried to sum a particular column by searching through the column names that are available in a sheet, but it's throwing some error , were i couldn't overcome that error.Can anyone help me out this

Thank you in advance

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim c As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Fnd = sh.Rows(1).Find("Basic", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    lr = Fnd.Cells(Fnd.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        Fnd.Cells(lr + 1, 0).Formula = "=SUM(" & Fnd.Range(Fnd.Cells(2, 0), Fnd.Cells(lr, 0)).Address & ")"
    Else
        MsgBox "Search Item Not Found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your `Fnd` range is just the cell where VBA found `"Basic"` so your code referencing it will all go wrong. I'm not sure what do you want to do, but for what I can see you just need to find the column, end down and `FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-1]C)"`

Comment: I am new to this coding language, and i am trying to find a column name "Basic " and finding sum of that particular column, without knowing the column number

Comment: Check my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim RngToSum As Range, StrFind As String, ws As Worksheet, Col As Integer, LastRow As Long

    StrFind = "Basic"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Col = 0
        On Error Resume Next 'Error handler
        Col = .Cells.Find(StrFind).Column 'Find the column
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not Col = 0 Then 'If the item is found
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row 'the last row of that column
            Set RngToSum = .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(LastRow, Col)) 'Set the range
            .Cells(LastRow + 1, Col) = Application.Sum(RngToSum) 'sum the range on the next available row
        Else
            MsgBox "Search Item Not Found!"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: NAILED IT! Thank you for the assist,Damain

Comment: Of it helped don't forget to mark it as answer so others may find it.

Comment: Damian, i have one more doubt that how to make that sum in negative and how to copy that particular sum

Comment: `Application.Sum(RngToSum) * -1` would do the negative. As per copy the value: `.Cells(LastRow + 1, Col).Copy`

Comment: NAILED IT! ,it worked perfectly,Thank you for the assist,Damain

Comment: "Application.Sum(RngToSum) * -1" instead of this can we do this "= -Application.Sum(RngToSum)"